# Alternatives to LINQ To SQL on high loaded pages

Tags: linq-to-sql

To begin with, I LOVE LINQ TO SQL. It's so much easier to use than direct querying.

But, there's one great problem: it doesn't work well on high loaded requests. I have some actions in my ASP.NET MVC project, that are called hundreds times every minute.

I used to have LINQ to SQL there, but since the amount of requests is gigantic, LINQ TO SQL almost always returned "Row not found or changed" or "X of X updates failed". And it's understandable. For instance, I have to increase some value by one with every request.

```
var stat = DB.Stats.First();
stat.Visits++;
// ....
DB.SubmitChanges();
```

But while ASP.NET was working on those //... instructions, the stats.Visits value stored in the table got changed.

I found a solution, I created a stored procedure

UPDATE Stats SET Visits=Visits+1

It works well.

Unfortunately now I'm getting more and more moments like that. And it sucks to create stored procedures for all cases.

So my question is, how to solve this problem? Are there any alternatives that can work here?

I hear that Stackoverflow works with LINQ to SQL. And it's more loaded than my site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't exactly a problem with Linq to SQL, per se, it's an expected result with optimistic concurrency, which Linq to SQL uses by default.

Optimistic concurrency means that when you update a record, you check the current version in the database against the copy that was originally retrieved before making any offline updates; if they don't match, report a concurrency violation ("row not found or changed").

There's a more detailed explanation of this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399373.aspx).  There's also a fairly sizable [guide on handling concurrency errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.changeconflictexception.aspx).  Typically the solution involves simply catching `ChangeConflictException` and picking a resolution, such as:

```
try
{
    // Make changes
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (ChangeConflictException)
{
    foreach (var conflict in db.ChangeConflicts)
    {
        conflict.Resolve(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues);
    }
}
```

The above version will overwrite whatever is in the database with the current values, regardless of what other changes were made.  For other possibilities, see the [RefreshMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.refreshmode.aspx) enumeration.

Your other option is to disable optimistic concurrency entirely for fields that you expect might be updated.  You do this by setting the `UpdateCheck` option to `UpdateCheck.Never`.  This has to be done at the field level; you can't do it at the entity level or globally at the context level.

Maybe I should also mention that you haven't picked a very good design for the specific problem you're trying to solve.  Incrementing a "counter" by repeatedly updating a single column of a single row is not a very good/appropriate use of a relational database.  What you should be doing is actually maintaining a history table - such as `Visits` - and if you really need to denormalize the count, implement that with a trigger in the database itself.  Trying to implement a site counter at the application level without any data to back it up is just asking for trouble.

Use your application to put actual *data* in your database, and let the database handle aggregates - that's one of the things databases are good at.

Comment: But this solution does not work for this particular problem of counting visits: no matter what resolution strategy you adopt, you will end up losing (i.e. not counting) some visits.

Comment: @Fyodor: Quite the contrary, did you read the last two paragraphs?  If you have the application append data to a transactional table then you can never lose any updates because you are never updating, only inserting.

Comment: The last two paragraphs were added after I fetched the initial version of the answer, so I had no chance to read them. Now that I've read them, I must object anyway: this is a questionable solution. While it may be acceptable in some cases, the general strategy of keeping full history of your operation is also asking for trouble. The time will inevitably come when you'll have to implement some sort of history archiving and rolling up the aggregates. And that means that you have to think about it in advance, or else you're doomed. And that significantly increases complexity.

Comment: ...and it's probably not worth it, given the simple task of counting visitors. (sorry, comment limit)

Comment: @Fyodor: This is nonsense.  If the site gets 1 million unique visitors per day, it will be *years* before that even makes a dent in aggregate performance.  Archiving is hardly a difficult problem to solve, "rolling up the aggregates" is a 1-line `COUNT(*)` query, and if necessary it can be denormalized with a 5-line trigger.  This is Databases 101 here, and it's how hundreds if not thousands of site analytics tools *actually work*.

Comment: I agree with Fyodor on this. If you can't trust LINQ to SQL or an application to increment a simple value, then that is a pretty fundamental issue to me. Further, you may wish to store a row in the Visits table AS WELL AS incrementing a simple counter at the application level. Who said applications aren't allowed to perform SomeInt++; ??? Seems pretty lame to me that you are defending it so hard. No I don't want to end up with zillions of triggers all through my database for every time this error occurs. That's why I have an "application" so that it can easily be released anywhere all intact.

Comment: @Aaron: Please read on [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). I'm not going to waste time arguing with somebody who doesn't understand fundamental database concepts.

Comment: You are the classic mad professor Aaron. The guy who lives in a world of perfection striving to over engineer simple things and bloat the employer's IT budget. I sorted out a nice, elegant solution which works great. As I was already storing each view as a separate row anyway, on page load, I now simply also tally them up and *attempt* to update the ViewCount field. 9/10 times, it happens gracefully, 1/10 times, LINQ to SQL won't allow the update (due to the optimistic concurrency). That's fine, it'll update next time when there is no concurrency conflict. I'm storing all the rows anyway.

Comment: @Aaron: So in other words you did exactly what I suggested in my second-to-last paragraph here, called it your own solution, and criticized me for over-engineering?  Way to go, you win the BDITU award for tonight.

Comment: Um, no. No database triggers here, all achieved within the application.  I was already recording the rows for each page visit. I simply changed the way I maintained my ViewCount field from the ViewCount++ method, to instead re-totalling all page hit rows each time. Now I don't have the hassle of your solution in needing to worry about database triggers lurking behind the scenes in the database. The more of these things you add around the place, the more things for new developers to trip up on when code changes hands in 3 years time. KISS principle applies here.

Comment: @Aaron, just go away and stop lighting up my inbox, if you think you have such a brilliant answer then post it as one and see what the community thinks of it through votes. FYI, "re-totalling all page hit rows each time" completely negates the performance benefit of denormalizing the field in the first place, so congratulations on coming up with a design that incorporates the worst of both worlds (inconsistent updates due to concurrency ignorance *and* the perf hit of a table/index scan).

Answer (score 3):

Use a producer/consumer or message queue model for updates that don't absolutely have to happen immediately, particularly status updates.  Instead of trying to update the database immediately keep a queue of updates that the asp.net threads can push to and then have a writer process/thread that writes the queue to the database.  Since only one thread is writing, there will be much less contention on the relevant tables/roles.

For reads, use caching.  For high volume sites even caching data for a few seconds can make a difference.

Comment: This reeks of additional complexity. No we don't need a message queue to increment in integer thanks. Over-engineering 101 which always leads to failure. You'll spend 95% of your time being a message queue admin solving other/new surprises and random problems with that.

Comment: @Aaron, I'm sorry if you feel a producer/consumer queue is too complex for you to implement. It's a very common pattern and helps in many situations. Delayed writes, particularly if you aggregate the writes, is an excellent example.

Comment: No its not complex, this is the difference between being a mad professor or "getting your product out there". Too many satellite systems reeks of over engineering. I sorted out a nice, elegant solution which works great. As I was already storing each view as a separate row anyway, on page load, I now simply also tally them up and *attempt* to update the ViewCount field. 9/10 times, it happens gracefully, 1/10 times, LINQ to SQL won't allow the update (due to the optimistic concurrency). That's fine, it'll update next time when there is no concurrency conflict. I'm storing all the rows anyway.

Comment: @Aaron, sounds like you're losing 10% of your data.  Great solution.

Comment: No, a row is ALWAYS stored on every page hit. That succeeds 100% of the time, because its just an insert. Totally reliable. I have another field called ViewCount which is a total of those rows. Updating this ViewCount field only succeeds 9/10 times. If it fails, it updates correctly next time. Worst case is that the contents of ViewCount, is slightly outdated to the user who's seeing it. But 5 seconds later it would be current again when the next update succeeds. No data is lost.

Comment: @Aaron, oh, I see, you're storing calculated data.  I never would have expected that, you know, normalization rules and all.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could call `DB.SubmitChanges()` right after `stats.Visits++`, and that would greatly reduce the problem.

However, that still is not going to save you from the concurrency violation (that is, simultaneously modifying a piece of data by two concurrent processes). To fight that, you may use the standard mechanism of *transactions*. With LINQ-to-SQL, you use transactions by instantiating a `TransactionScope` class, thusly:

```
using( TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope() )
{
    var stats = DB.Stats.First();
    stats.Visits++;
    DB.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**Update**: *as Aaronaught correctly pointed out, TransactionScope is not going to help here, actually. Sorry. But read on.*

Be careful, though, not to make the body of a transaction too long, as it will block other concurrent processes, and thus, significantly reduce your overall performance.

And that brings me to the next point: your very design is probably flawed.

The core principle in dealing with highly shared data is to design your application in such way that the operations on that data are quick, simple, and semantically clear, and they must be performed one after another, not simultaneously.

The one operation that you're describing - counting visits - is pretty clear and simple, so it should be no problem, once you add the transaction. I must add, however, that while this will be clear, type-safe and otherwise "good", the solution with stored procedure is actually a much preferred one. This is actually exactly the way database applications were being designed in ye olden days. Think about it: why would you need to fetch the counter all the way from the database to your application (potentially over the network!) if there is no business logic involved in processing it. The database server may increment it just as well, without even sending anything back to the application.

Now, as for other operations, that are hidden behind `// ...`, it seems (by your description) that they're somewhat heavy and long. I can't tell for sure, because I don't see what's there, but if that's the case, you probably want to separate them into smaller and quicker ones, or otherwise rethink your design. I really can't tell anything else with this little information.

Comment: Sorry, but using a `TransactionScope` here doesn't change a thing.  You would need `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level or an `UPDLOCK` to actually ensure that one transaction's read happens after the other transaction's update; but even if you could do that using L2S (which you can't), it would completely kill performance.

Comment: Ummm... Yes, you're right that TransactionScope is not going to do the trick. The second statement, though, is beside the point: I do discuss  performance and design afterwards.

Comment: Right, or just use a log table, which you'll be glad to have when your customer/employer asks you to back up your number and/or perform some actual analysis on hits.  Because it *will* happen, guaranteed.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I need to move simple stuff like increasing stats to stored procedure? (Actually I already did that)

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. Type safety and all the bells and whistles is sure nice, but you have to always keep in mind what you're trading off for the convenience.

Comment: Sure, I actually have a LOG table, but I also want to record this simple increment as well. To save processing later, because its easy to do "while I'm there". I also use my log table to aggregate other stats and do some clever magic with later on.. But pretty lame that I can't increment a simple integer. There should be a way to lock LINQ into fetching and incrementing the value atomically so that no other process can interfere in between that "atomic" transaction.